A basic question about differentiation
Good evening. I have a basic question about differentiation.
Let $a,b$ two distinct real numbers. Let $f : [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function such that $f'(a)<0$.
I wanna prove that statement
very rigorously : $$\exists \eta >0, \hspace{1mm} \exists y \in [a,a+\eta[, \hspace{1mm} f(y)-f(a) < 0$$

My attempt : By definition we have : $$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} = f'(a) $$
It means that : $$ \forall \varepsilon > 0, \hspace{1mm} \exists \eta >0, \hspace{1mm} \forall x \in [a,b], \hspace{1mm} x-a < \eta \implies \hspace{1mm}  \left| \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} - f'(a) \right| < \varepsilon$$
Thus : $$ \forall \varepsilon > 0, \hspace{1mm} \exists \eta >0, \hspace{1mm} \forall x \in [a,a+\eta[, \hspace{1mm}  \left| \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} - f'(a) \right| < \varepsilon$$

Even if I try to chose a good $\varepsilon$ it seems like it's a dead end.
I know that the function isn't necessarily decreasing in a neighbourhood of $a$ (if we consider $g : x \longmapsto x^2\cos\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$ with $g(0) = 0$ there are no neighbourhood of $0$ such that the function is strictly increasing or decreasing)
But in our general case I'm almost sure that we can atleast find a neighbourood of $a$ containing a point $y$ such that $f(y)-f(a) <0$. If you have any clue I will be grateful.

If such neighbourhood does not exist (that is $f(y) - f(a) \ge 0$ for all $y$), how it is possible that $f'(a) < 0$?

Take $\varepsilon=|f'(a)|$. There is some $\delta>0$ such that, if $|y-a|<\delta$, then$$\left|\frac{f(y)-f(a)}{y-a}-f'(a)\right|<|f'(a)|.$$But then $\frac{f(y)-f(a)}{y-a}<0$. So, if $a<y<a+\delta$, then, since $y-a>0$, $f(y)-f(a)<0$.

Why your inequality implies $\frac{f(y)-f(a)}{y-a}<0$ ?

If $b<0\leqslant c$, then $|b-c|=c-b\geqslant-b=|b|$. Now, apply this to $b=\frac{f(y)-f(a)}{y-a}$ and $c=f'(a)$.

I meant to write $b=f'(a)$ and $c=\frac{f(y)-f(a)}{y-a}$.
